# Python String replace doesn't work

Tags: python, string

I am trying to do a replace for something in a string. Here is the code I am testing:

```
stringT = "hello world"
print(stringT)
stringT.replace("world", "all")
print(stringT)
```

I would expect the second output to say 'hello all' but it says 'hello world' both times. There are no errors, the code runs fine, it just doesn't do anything. How do I fix this?

Comment: `str.replace()` doesn't change your string in-place. You need to reassign the result after replacing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  That means that they cannot be changed.  `stringT.replace(...)` does not change `stringT` itself; it returns a new string.  Change that line to:

```
stringT = stringT.replace("world", "all")
```